# "Copy Link" not available while trying to share a file from iCloud from Finder

Tags: icloud, finder

I'm trying to follow the documentation for sharing a file on iCloud from Finder:
https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/mac-help/mchl91854a7a/12.0/mac/12.0

My Share Menu looks completely different from the one shown in the manual, and no "Copy Link" option is displayed:

[image]

My OSX version is 12.6.5 Monterey. Any idea how to create a shareable link from Finder?

ps. The file is located inside iCloud folder obviously, and I can manage to get a link to it if I go to the iCloud website, but I would like to be able to generate it from finder, which would be much more convenient.

Comment: What if you click on "More"?

Comment: @Thinkr It allow you to configure the elements of the menu, but "Copy Link" is not there.